# Why check for zero-account?

Tags: require

I see `require(account != address(0x0));` as somewhat of a boilerplate check for some functions. Is the purpose just to add a check that prevents the creation of a new contract?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 0x0 address you can see it here : https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This address is the owner of every ERC20 / NFT tokens when they are not claimed yet. Of course it's a dead address that nobody control. So it's important in your contract to blacklist it so you cannot "burn" token to this address. And because address is null there is a lot of bugs in your code if you don't blacklist them.

Comment: Mark as an answer then, please